# The Group of Bounded Permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Let
$$
S_B = \{\phi\in S_\mathbb{N} 
\mid \exists R\in\mathbb{N}: 
|\phi_n-n|\leq R\}.
$$

Does anyone know if this subgroup has been well studied? Has it been given a name in the literature? I am hoping for a full characterization of its normal subgroups. The only ones I have found are those inherited by $S_\mathbb{N}$ (those in the Schreier-Ulam theorem).

Comment: This is hardly different from your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4746081/the-subgroup-of-bounded-permutations#comment10069548_4746081

Comment: Found these: https://escholarship.org/content/qt5sj0d2v2/qt5sj0d2v2.pdf?t=lnrllu, https://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=timm&paperid=1914&option_lang=eng

Comment: @Ben That's gonna be a tough translate haha, I'll try and pick out what I can from it, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a construction of many normal subgroups of $S_B$. Given two increasing functions $f, g : \mathbb N \to [0, \infty)$, let us write $f \prec g$ if there are constants $a, b$ such that $f(x) \le a g(x + b)$ for all $x \in \mathbb N$. Now given an increasing function $f : \mathbb N \to [1,\infty)$ let$\def\supp{\operatorname{supp}}$

$$N_f = \{\pi \in S_B \mid |\supp(\pi) \cap [0,n]| \prec f\}.$$

Since $\supp(\pi\sigma) \subset \supp(\pi) \cup \supp(\sigma)$ it is clear that $N_f$ is a subgroup and if $\phi \in S_B$ and $|\phi(n) - n| \le R$ for all $n$ then $|\supp(\pi^\phi) \cap [0,n]| \le |\supp(\pi) \cap [0, n+R]|$, so $N_f$ is actually a normal subgroup. Moreover $N_f$ contains the subgroup $\mathrm{FSym}(\mathbb N)$ of all finitely supported permutations.

By considering $f(n) = n^\alpha$ for $0 < \alpha < 1$, we get continuum-many normal subgroups in this way (note that $n^\alpha \prec n^\beta$ iff $\alpha \le \beta$). With other choices of $f$ we can also get a large collection of pairwise incomparable normal subgroups (neither contained in the other).

---

Edit: Here is a contruction of $2^c$ pairwise incomparable normal subgroups of $S_B$ (where $c = 2^{\aleph_0}$). Let $\beta \mathbb N$ be the set of ultrafilters. It is well-known that $|\beta \mathbb N| = 2^c$ (for example this follows from the fact that $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ is separable). Now for any $p \in \beta \mathbb N$ consider

$$N_p = \{\pi \in S_B \mid \limsup_{n \to p} |\supp(\pi) \cap [0,2^{2^n}]| / 2^{2^n} = 0\}.$$

It follows exactly as above that $N_p \trianglelefteq S_B$ for all $p \in \beta\mathbb N \setminus \mathbb N$.
Now consider two ultrafilters $p, q \in \beta\mathbb N \setminus \mathbb N$. Let $X \in p \setminus q$. Let $\pi \in S_B$ the product of all transpositions $(2i, 2i+1)$ where $2^{2^{n-1}} \le 2i < 2^{2^n}$ for $n \in X$. Then $\pi \in N_q \setminus N_p$, which demonstrates that $N_q \not\le N_p$.

Comment: Looks great! I'm gonna spend some time digesting it, after which I'll grant you the bounty. Did you come up with this or did you find it somewhere?

Comment: @MilesGould I spent 20-30 minutes thinking about whether the proof of Schreier--Ulam could be adapted, but it turns out it can't be because it's difficult to move supports around as much as one needs. This leads naturally the construction above. It is also reasonable in view of Schreier--Ulam to guess that something like support size is the only important invariant, but once you place a metric structure on the domain (by specifying bounded permutations) you can make sense of support size in metric ways (as above).

Comment: Impressive! So this question relates to a paper I'm writing. Would you be okay with me including this in it? If so, how should I credit you?

Comment: @MilesGould No problem. You can use the "cite" button at the bottom of the answer to generate some bibtex code for citing this answer in your paper. Feel free to paraphrase the answer in your paper.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm not 100% sure I'll be using it (my coauthor is the algebraist, I'm the analyst). Regardless, the idea behind the construction will be a useful tool.

Comment: Cool note: If you close the endpoints of the continuum example you gave, namely $f(n)=(n+1)^0$ and $f(n)=(n+1)^1$ you get $FSym(\mathbb{N})$ and $S_B$ respectively, so this is an ascending chain of normal subgroups connecting the two largest normal subgroups which follow from Schreier_Ulam.

Comment: It also appears to be true that if $f\prec g,$ then $N_f$ is a normal subgroup of $N_g.$ Nothing in the proof should change if we replace the normalizing group $S_B$ by $N_g.$

Comment: @MilesGould In general, if $N \le H \le G$ and $N$ is normal in $G$ then $N$ is normal in $H$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148065/discussion-between-miles-gould-and-sean-eberhard).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the answer from @Sean Eberhard, I found this normal proper subgroup, which is the largest I could find.
$$N_O=\{\phi\in S_B\mid n\neq O\left(|\mathrm{supp}(\phi)\cap[0,n]|\right)\},$$
where $O$ denotes the big O operator.

Comment: ...in other words $\liminf |\mathrm{supp}(\phi) \cap [0,n]| / n = 0$.

Comment: But that's not a subgroup. Let $X \cup Y$ be a decomposition of $\mathbb N$ into two sets of zero lower density. For example let $X$ be the set of $n$ such that $\lfloor \log\log n \rfloor$ is even and let $Y$ be the complement. Now let $x$ be an infinite cycle with support $X$ and let $y$ be an infinite cycle with support $Y$. Then $x, y \in N_O$ but $xy$ has full support so $xy \notin N_O$. Switch to upper density instead.